# 403: Forbidden Error in AngularJS Website ON IIS 7.0

Tags: c#, angularjs, iis-7, asp.net-web-api2

I deployed 2 projects under one domain(1.AngularJS and 2.MVCWebAPI).

IN Parent Root i deployed AngularJS Project and WebAPI Project Deployed Under Child root,Example of My Website Structure on IIS 7.0:

For example,
1)AngularJS Website under C:\Inetpub\myproject\

2) MVCWebAPI under C:\Inetpub\myproject\api

I was converted api folder to application from IIS, So api project run with same domain.

Here Issue Occurred with AngularJS Website, when i try to access site from browser then error occurred like 403: forbidden access denied, after refreshing browser more than one times, it's work properly, but when clear the cache of browser then same issue occurred.

I searched about this error but all of say it's need to give a permission to user to access directory, but i already give it.

[image]